# mod_wsgi: How to run different apps under single domain?

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, vhosts

I have a domain *example.com* and I run a standard Apache there (serving static files and PHP). I want to run Python served pages on *subdomain.example.com*.

I managed to configure Apache to do this and there is a Flask app running at *subdomain.example.com*. However, in the virtual host config file, the whole subdomain is tight to this one single app. I would like to go further and run several different apps on this subdomain.

For example:

subdomain.example.com/app1/ would run /var/www/apps/app1/app.wsgi
subdomain.example.com/app2/ would run /var/www/apps/app2/app.wsgi

and so on...

Furthermore I would like this to be fully automatic, that is when I set up new folder in */var/www/apps/*, I could reach the app through the Apache without further configuration.

I can see several ways of doing this:

1. Configure Apache to route every *subdomain.example.com* request
   to a single "meta app" in Python which would run a specific app
   based on given URL.
2. Do some magic with Apache configuration that would take care of
   this automatically.
3. Maybe use *nginx*? I don't really have much experience with this,
   but someone told me this could solve the problem.

Is there any best practice about how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should be able to do this by providing a directory path (in your case, `/var/www/apps`) to the `WSGIScriptAlias` directive. Read more here:

https://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIScriptAlias.html

This seems like a neater solution than using a meta app.